# ASP.Net MVC5: Area Layout changes during RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've used below snippet to redirect user to different action/views based on selected contract type:

```
public ActionResult Create(ContractViewModelCreate contract)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (contract.ContractType == Contract.ContractTypeENUM.SectionBased)
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "SectionBasedContract", new { area = "Admin" });
        else if (contract.ContractType == Contract.ContractTypeENUM.UnitBased)
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "UnitBasedContract", new { area = "Admin" });
        else
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Utils.AddErrorsString(ModelState, "Select project type");
    return View(contract);
}
```

However the first `RedirectToAction` leads to reading of layout file by running _ViewStart.cs in `Admin` area and 2nd one leads to running to _ViewStart.cs in root application area and don't care about Route Objects (to run in Admin Area).
Since this action is running inside Admin area running of `return RedirectToAction("Create", "UnitBasedContract", new { area = "Admin" });` lead to layout change.

I cannot find the reason, does anyone knows the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The problem caused by the fact that I forgot to move View files of `UnitBasedContractController` to `Admin` area and I had left them in global application area. So the `_ViewStart.cs` of global Views called for my Views.